# How to automatically select idle GPU for model traning in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia-docker

I am using nvidia prebuilt docker container `NVIDIA Release 20.12-tf2` to run my experiment. I am using `TensorFlow Version 2.3.1`. Currently, I am running my model on one of GPU, I still have 3 more idle GPUs so I intend to use my alternative experiment on any idle GPUs. Here is the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:6A:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   70C    P0    71W /  70W |  14586MiB / 15109MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:6B:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    27W /  70W |    212MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:6C:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   41C    P0    28W /  70W |    212MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:6D:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   41C    P0    28W /  70W |    212MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**update: prebuilt -container**:

I'm using nvidia-prebuilt container as follow:

```
docker run -ti --rm --gpus all --shm-size=1024m -v /home/hamilton/data:/data nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.12-tf2-py3
```

To utilize idle GPU for my other experiments, I tried to add those in my python script:

**attempt-1**

```
import tensorflow as tf

devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(devices[0], True)
```

but this attempt gave me following error:

> ```
> raise ValueError("Memory growth cannot differ between GPU devices") ValueError: Memory growth cannot differ between GPU devices
> ```

I googled this error but none of them discussed on GitHub is not working for me.

**attempt-2**

I also tried this:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

but this attempt also gave me error like this:

> Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed
> precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process
> may be terminated.

people discussed this error on github but still not able to get rid of error on my side.

**latest attempt**:

I also tried  parallel training with TensorFlow and added those to my python script:

```
device_type = "GPU"
devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type)
devices_names = [d.name.split("e:")[1] for d in devices]
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=devices_names[:3])

with strategy.scope():
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but this gave me also error and the program stopped.

Can anyone help me how to automatically select idle GPUs for the training model in tensorflow? Does anyone know any workable approach? What's wrong with my above attempt? Any possible ideas to utilize idle GPUs while running the program on one of the GPUs? any thoughts?

Comment: What about running a docker container with just the gpu(s) that you want instead of all? You could use something like `-gpus device=0` and `-gpus device=1`. See: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#gpu.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I can try it real quick and let you if it works.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón sweet, it worked! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HernánAlarcón suggestion, I tried like this and it worked like charm:

```
docker run -ti --rm --gpus device=1,3 --shm-size=1024m -v /home/hamilton/data:/data nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.12-tf2-py3
```

this may not be an elegant solution but it worked like charm. I am open to other possible remedies to fix this sort of problem.